# jQuery Time Error, 12:00 shows up as 12

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom script that shows the current time in several cities in the format HH:MM AM/PM. For some reason, if the time is 12:00-12:59 AM/PM, it shows up as just 12. I don't see what's wrong with it, can someone figure it out?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function calculateTime(offset) {
        var currentDate = new Date()
        utc = currentDate.getTime() + (currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
        newDate = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
        var minutes = newDate.getMinutes();
        if(minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        return (newDate.getHours() === 0) ? 12 : ((newDate.getHours() > 12) ? newDate.getHours() - 12 : newDate.getHours()) + ' : ' + minutes + ' ' + ((newDate.getHours() >  11) ? 'PM' : 'AM');
    }
    function displayTimes() {
        $(".chicago").html(calculateTime("-6"));
        $(".london").html(calculateTime("+0"));`
        $(".shanghai").html(calculateTime("+8"));
        $(".sydney").html(calculateTime("+9"));
    };
    displayTimes();
    window.setInterval(displayTimes, 5000);
});
```

I'm also looking in to adjusting for daylight savings time, but I think I should be able to figure that out on my own (but if anyone knows how to do this easily, please let me know!).

I had gotten a bit of help with this on Stack Overflow before, so whatever's causing it is probably something I didn't write myself (and therefore don't understand). An explination as to why it doesn't work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out based on that explanation! Posting an answer below.

Comment: It looks like code written by a PHP programmer.  The JavaScript `? :` operator binds the right way, as opposed to the same operator in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some bracket, try this:

```
return ((newDate.getHours() === 0) ? 12 : ((newDate.getHours() > 12) ? newDate.getHours() - 12 : newDate.getHours())) + ' : ' + minutes + ' ' + ((newDate.getHours() >  11) ? 'PM' : 'AM');
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's cleaner than the fix I had found seconds before you posted this. My fix was `return (newDate.getHours() === 0) ? 12 + ' : ' + minutes + ' ' + ((newDate.getHours() >  11) ? 'PM' : 'AM') : ((newDate.getHours() > 12) ? newDate.getHours() - 12 : newDate.getHours()) + ' : ' + minutes + ' ' + ((newDate.getHours() >  11) ? 'PM' : 'AM');`